# Can not find library headers in google cloud vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I've set up a Google Compute Engine VM(Ubuntu) and logged in via ssh.
Everything was good, but I could not see any header file(.h) in the /usr/local/include when I tried to install library like GMP, M4 ...

Steps:
1. git clone ...
2. ./configure && make
3. ls /usr/local/include (result: null)

Anyone knows what is wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found reason: I did not use sudo when I tried to install my library and it cause permission issues that /usr/local/include was not allowed to write.